# Why isn't this login view working? (Django)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a login view with Django's cache system. Here's my code so far:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = LoginForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            cd = form.cleaned_data
            username_exists = User.objects.filter(username=cd['username1'])
            if username_exists.count() != 0:
                username = username_exists[0]
                if username.password == cd['password']:
                    currentuser = cd['username1']
                    request.session['loggedin'+currentuser] = True
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/%' % currentuser)
                else:
                    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
                    return render_to_response('login.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
            else:
                form = LoginForm(request.POST)
                return render_to_response('login.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            form = LoginForm(request.POST)
            return render_to_response('login.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        return render_to_response('login.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My model that I'm using in the database is below:

```
class User(models.Model):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

Here's the form, "LoginForm":

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):

    username1 = forms.CharField(max_length=15, label="Username")
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=25, widget=forms.PasswordInput, label="Password")
```

Here's part of the template that I'm using:

```
<h3>Login</h3>

<form action="" method="post">

{% csrf_token %}

<table>

{{ form.as_table }}

</table>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-left:170px;margin-top:50px;">

</form>
```

Instead of redirecting to the user page, the view just refreshes the login page with the form information still filled in (request.POST).

I'm sort of new to Django so please alert me if I'm doing something really stupid.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this the User model in `contrib.auth` or a User model you've created?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your final success clause involves checking a password directly vs `user.password` which is a one way hashed password.  So you're likely checking `mypassword` vs `sha1$b322a$7e51a244d45f70d17b0bbca2b7369c1732b09c69`

Instead, use `django.contrib.auth.check_password` or the `authenticate` function which will do the password comparison for you and also log the user in. You seem to be doing some kind of manual login where a session flag is placed marking the user as logged in. All of your users would be `AnoymousUser` objects, too : )

Read up on the authentication framework... `django.contrib.auth` is fantastically useful.

If you use the built in functions, you can use simpler shortcuts like `request.user.is_authenticated()` to determine logged in status.

Anyways, preaching aside, to manually check a password:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/auth/#manually-checking-a-user-s-password

To actually log somebody in using the framework:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate

Another problem with your code is that it's difficult to tell what failed - the user / you will not be getting useful information about how his login failed.

Generally, it's best to put this information in your form clean methods so that you can raise `ValidationErrors` which will automatically appear in your form without cluttering with multiple if blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You're re-inventing the wheel. The User model from contrib.auth already checks for duplicate usernames.

If you want to provide your own form and view for creating users, almost all of the code you need is already present in contrib.auth.